# Как можно конвертировать файл из ogg в mp3 с помощью python в Windows

Tags: python, аудио, mp3, ogg

Необходимо воспроизвести файл **ogg** как звук, но ни одна библиотека **python** не позволяет это сделать. Решение - конвертировать в **mp3**. Но я не нашёл как выполнить эту задачу. И во всех "решениях" появлялась ошибка "*FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл*", что невозможно, ибо директория верна и работает с другими файлами. Но именно **ogg** не находит.

Comment: Посмотрите PySoundFile https://pypi.org/project/PySoundFile/, mp3 не вижу, но wav и ogg есть.

Comment: pygame.mixer.Sound поддерживает только файлы .wav и .ogg.